# Android: Google Map Split using Polygon

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon, android-maps-v2

Is it possible to split entire google map  into X km2 squares using polygon in  android? I don't know it's possible or not. If possible , please help how can we implement this. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274766/can-google-maps-v3-api-be-used-to-split-a-polygon-but-keep-one-namespace. Splitting of polygon was discuss here.

Comment: Actually I need to get entire coordinates list of X km2 bound to split map in android.